# SWT Table - Deselecting a Row after it has been selected

Tags: java, swt, selection

When I select a row in my table, there is no way to deselect that row.  Unless there is two rows in the table.  Then I can select the other row.  Now the 2nd row is selected and the 1st row is deselected. I thought by selecting the selected row again, that would deselect the row.  But that does not seem to be the case for me.

```
viewer = new AplotDataTableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.MULTI|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
```

I really don't want to have to create a button to deselect current selections.

Comment: you can do it with the help of a listener and then deselecting

Comment: TableViewer.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY) should deselect the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TableViewer.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY) was the way I corrected the issue.

Sambi Reddy provided me with the solution